# Как выделять TreeViewItem, если в его шаблоне есть TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть `TreeView`, у которого в шаблоне есть `TextBox` для того, чтобы текстовую информацию можно было выделять и копировать. Так вот, когда я щелкаю по `TextBox`, сам TreeViewItem при этом не выделяется. А надо, чтобы выделялся. Как такое осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, вам нужен добавить триггер для `TreeViewItem`.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

(если стиль уже есть, просто добавьте триггер).

<sub>Честно украдено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7990493/276994).</sub>